# How to make requests to an api until have the expected result

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, fetch

There's a URL with a json. sometimes the data retrieved doesnt has the data that i want, then i would like to request it four more times, till i get the correct result. How can i do this by the right way ? When i call this, the return get really fast.. it fells it isnt making 5 requests, but only one.

I am calling the TryToUpdate function.

```js
const getText = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var retorno;
  fetch('URL').then(i => i.json()).then(i => {
    retorno = i ? .result[0] ? .edited_channel_post ? .text;
    if (retorno.includes('Texto:')) {
      resolve({
        data: retorno,
      });
    } else {
      reject('unavailable');
    }
  })
})

async function tryToUpdate(tries = 0) {
  var retorno;
  var tryNum = tries
  if (tries >= 5) {
    console.log('Cant update.');
    return undefined;
  } else {
    getText
      .then(i => retorno)
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('Cannot reach result. Try num:' + tryNum);
        tryToUpdate(tryNum + 1);

      });
  }
}
```

I tried to make 5 requests to a URL till i get the expected result.

Comment: You could try putting a `console.log` in to check that your getText function is being called five times. It may just be it is happening so quickly that it feels like it's all at once. You don't have a delay here, so it's likely that is what is happening. Check this out for potentially how to put in a delay https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72972814/setting-a-delay-in-fetch-api-call

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding the problem is a UX problem, that is, it is happening too quickly. You can wait for a while if there was a problem, like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    tryToUpdate(tryNum+1);
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be thought of as a promise chain that's built conditionally.  Below, the function `tryToUpdate`  catches errors, pauses and recurses up to 5 times.

```js
// generic pause code
const pause = async (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

// this is the OP's fetch rewritten to demo.  see note below the snippet
function getText(invocation) {
  // pause 100ms, fail on the first few, then succeed
  return pause(100).then(() => {
    if (invocation < 3) throw 'failure';
    return Promise.resolve('success')
  })
}

function tryToUpdate(invocation=0) {
  return getText(invocation).catch(error => {
    if (invocation < 5) {
      console.log('failed, retrying')
      // the OP should select an appropriate pause.
      // no pause might be too fast for the api
      return pause(1000).then(() => tryToUpdate(invocation+1))
    } else {
      console.log('failed, and no more retry')
      throw error
    }
  })
}

tryToUpdate().then(console.log)
```

The OP's fetch can be improved by not creating a new Promise...

```
const getText = url => {
  return fetch('URL').then(i => i.json()).then(i => {
    retorno = i?.result[0]?.edited_channel_post?.text;
    return retorno.includes('Texto:') ? { data: retorno } : throw 'unavailable';
  })
}
```

Comment: It's good practice to progressively wait longer times to account for times when the server is busy, such as: `pause((invocation + 1) * (invocation + 1) * 1000)`, which waits 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36 secs